# Translation in parameter of translation with Thymeleaf

Tags: internationalization, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf 3.0.9, suppose I have this translation:

```
hello=Hello {0}
```

In my template, I have:

```
<span th:text="#{hello(${user.getName()})}"></span>
```

Now suppose `user.getName()` can be `null`, so I want to display something nice in that case:

```
<span th:text="#{hello(${user.getName()?:'Unknown'})}"></span>
```

This works fine.

Now I also want to tranlate `Unknown`, how can I do this?

I tried:

```
<span th:text="#{hello(${user.getName()?:#{unknown})}"></span>
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the `#messages` utility object:

```xml
<span th:text="#{hello(${user.getName()?:#messages.msg('unknown')})}"></span>
```

And add property in the messages file(s):

```
unknown=Unknown
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it does not work. It fails with `EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'`

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Ooups, got the parenthesis wrong, try update.